# Trying to find latest date in an array using max but getting different results

Tags: python, date

I am trying to find latest date in an array using python max but im getting different results

The expected result for this is fine

```
>>> a = ["10-09-1988","20-10-1999"]
>>> max(a)
'20-10-1999'
```

Since 20-10-1999 is latest date

But for this one

```
>>> a = ["10-10-1999","20-10-1988"]
>>> max(a)
'20-10-1988'
```

The expected output is

```
10-10-1999
```

Since 10-10-1999 is latest date but im getting 20-10-1988

How get latest date in array on elements in python (date format is dd-mm-yyy)

for the above one i want (10-10-1999) as output

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically, they are not date objects.

Comment: Convert the string to date object then compare the date.

Comment: It is giving correct result according to string comparison. convert it to datetime object and then compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `key` to convert the string to datetime object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = ["10-09-1988","20-10-1999"]
>>> max(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y"))
'20-10-1999'
```

Comment: How to make an if statement for this? **if a[0] is the latest date, then return 0, else if a[1] is the latest date, return 1**. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string to `datetime` object, or maybe this following code can do this:

```
>>> a = ["10-09-1988","20-02-1989","20-09-1988"]
>>> max(a,key=lambda x:(x[6:10],x[3:5],x[:2]))
'20-02-1989'
```

It is more efficient than convert string to `datetime` object:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> s = """
... a=['28-07-2002', '12-02-1976', '23-10-1967', '27-04-1913', '05-06-1901', '06-12-1964', '04-12-1982', '03-04-1929', '07-02-1943', '03-08-1955']
... import datetime
... max(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y"))
... """
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s,number=10000)
1.0200450420379639
>>> s = """
... a=['28-07-2002', '12-02-1976', '23-10-1967', '27-04-1913', '05-06-1901', '06-12-1964', '04-12-1982', '03-04-1929', '07-02-1943', '03-08-1955']
... import datetime
... max(a,key=lambda x:(x[6:10],x[3:5],x[:2]))
... """
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s,number=10000)
0.04339408874511719
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare them, you need to convert the date represented as string to `datetime` object.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = ["10-10-1999","20-10-1988"]
>>> for i, date in enumerate(a):
...     a[i] = datetime.strptime(a[i], "%d-%m-%Y")
...
>>> a
[datetime.datetime(1999, 10, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1988, 10, 20, 0, 0)]
>>> max(a)
datetime.datetime(1999, 10, 10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Gives me an error, I only had to add `from datetime import datetime` and it worked. The for loop gave me the error. So I deleted the for loop, now when I do `max(a)` I get the latest date in the array.

Comment: Is it possible to get the index of the value with latest date in the array? I will use this for an if statement. So **If `a[0]` is the latest, `aLatest = 0`** otherwise **if `a[1]` is the latest, `aLatest = 1`**